# cloudfoundry error pushing to bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am working my way through an [online course](https://developer.ibm.com/dwcourses/) from IBM on getting to know Bluemix. The exercise shows how to push an application to Bluemix.

I am running:

> cf version 6.18.1+a1103f0-2016-05-24 on a Mac running OS X El Capitan
>   10.11.5 (15F34)

This is the command I entered:

```
cf push leonardbMyFirstDeploy3 -c "node app.js" -m 128M --no-manifest --no-start
```

This is the error I am getting (I have substituted my user name and digits on Mobile Documents folder name).

> *FAILED
>
> Error processing app files in '/Users/**myname**': read
>   /Users/**myname**/Library/Mobile
>   Documents.###########/com~apple~TextInput/Dictionaries/.baseline/UserDictionary/SAlQVUhF7208e6_gvZx_zdKx1U1AzKGem3HO2pLKjgY=/baseline.zip:
>   bad file descriptor*

I checked the file and yes the file seems to be corrupted. As I understand, this directory is my local location for iCloud sharing on my local disk. I don't know how this dictionary file got there and probably don't need it.

But my questions are these:

1. For the cloud foundry push command is there a way to generate a trace to get more information?
2. Why would the push be even looking at or using the file that is giving it problems? This seems like a significant overreach to even be anywhere this this folder. So does anyone know why?
3. Can anyone advise how to fix this?

   I did try to configure a .cfignore using the Mobile                    Documents.########## directory but this did not seem to change the outcome any as the error recurred.
4. If the push command gives you OK on certain steps are there any cleanup or rollback commands that need to be executed before running again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `cf push` without the `-p` option, it will recursively push everything in the current directory and under it. So if you were running in `/Users/myname` when you ran the push, it will have pushed everything underneath it. Try creating a separate directory which contains just your app files and push from there instead.

If you run the `cf` command without any arguments it will dump a bunch of usage info, including the following environment variable to control debug tracing:

`CF_TRACE=true                      Print API request diagnostics to stdout`

Finally you do not have to clean anything up explicitly. If you do as I suggested above and move just your application files into their own directory and run the push from there, it will simply overwrite what you did before.

Comment: Thank you. You were spot on I believed I was in a sub directory but when I went back to the terminal and checked I was not in the directory I thought that I was.  Thanks also for the tip on the trace command.